# signIn function is throwing in Auth.js (NextAuth.js) and ignoring my catch

Tags: reactjs, authentication, next.js, next-auth

I'm using Next.js 14.0.3 with server actions and Auth.js 5.0.0-beta.4.

I'm trying to use Auth.js credentials provider. Similar to what Next tutorial had done [here](https://nextjs.org/learn/dashboard-app/adding-authentication).

However, when trying to login with invalid credentials, I get the error thrown on the server console.

The problem is, the `signIn` method is wrapped with `try/catch` so it shouldn't throw like this.
[image: server terminal window showing auth error message]

Here's my `actions.ts` file.

```
"use server";

import { signIn } from "@/auth";
import { AuthError } from "next-auth";

export async function authenticate(
  prevState: string | undefined,
  formData: FormData
) {
  try {
    await signIn("credentials", formData);
  } catch (error) {
    if (error instanceof AuthError) {
      switch (error.type) {
        case "CredentialsSignin":
          return "Invalid credentials.";
        default:
          return "Something went wrong.";
      }
    }
    throw error;
  }
}
```

And here's my `auth.ts` file:

```
export const { auth, signIn, signOut } = NextAuth({
  ...authConfig,
  providers: [
    Credentials({
      async authorize(credentials) {
        const validatedCredentials = CredentialsSchema.safeParse(credentials);

        if (validatedCredentials.success) {
          const { username, password } = validatedCredentials.data;

          const { user } = await findUserByUsername(username);

          if (!user) {
            return null;
          }

          const passwordMatch = await bcrypt.compare(password, user.password);

          if (passwordMatch) {
            return user;
          }
        }

        console.log("Invalid credentials.");
        return null;
      },
    }),
  ],
});
```

I'm seeing the `Invalid credentials.` being logged as well from the `auth.ts` file. So, I'm 100% sure that my `authorize` method is returning null.

Comment: I know it looks correct from the learning page code but, for me, the only reason that the error is thrown is because the error is not an instance of `AuthError`. Have you tried putting some debugging to verify the error in the catch section?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. In my case I needed to add "use server" at the top of both auth.ts and actions.ts which fixed it.